# R.layout.main not recognized

Tags: android

I'm trying to create the simplest hello world program but as soon as I create a new project, I get the following error: "main cannot be resolved or is not a field".

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Hello World!");
    setContentView(tv);
}
```

}

I've tried adding import.android.R;, cleaning and restarting. I've also deleted import.android.R and included import.com.example.helloworld.R; (my package name). Keep getting the same error.

Comment: why are you calling setContentView(tv);

Answer (score 3):

You've imported the Android's "R" class. You need to import your own.

Replace

```
import android.R;
```

With:

```
import com.example.helloworld.R;
```

If your R file doesn't resolve, then you have a problem in one of the files in your res folder. Check that all file names are lower case, have no illegal chars and that any XML files don't have syntax problems.

Answer (score 0):

check your error logs or lint messages. I was facing this problem a couple of times.

Last time it was an improperly generated menu.xml file. Removing helped